# What is the primary motivation behind combining A series and R series ARM onto an FPGA in MPSoC Xilinx devices?

Tags: xilinx

The first entry into the SoC series from Xilinx was the Zynq SoC. It combined ARM cortex A9 processor with programmable logic to get the best of both worlds.

The current generation contains Ultrascale+ devices that Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC and Zynq UltraScale+ RFSoC. These contain:

```
Dual or Quad Arm® Cortex®-A53
Dual Arm Cortex-R5F
```

What I fail to understand is, what would a person do with so many cores? And why mix A and R series ARM processors anyway? I don't know what the difference between them is. If we need processing power, we could just go for a DSP, GPU or something else isn't it? I am missing the point here actually.

Comment: Oh how soon the Virtex-II Pro and its embedded Power-PC was forgotten...

Comment: I have only heard of these names and know nothing about them actually.

Comment: Don't worry too much then. Xilinx was in the SoC business a long time before Zynq. (And probably before SoC was a recognized term)

Comment: *I don't know what the difference between them is* - maybe you should start with figuring it out?

Comment: *What I fail to understand is, what would a person do with so many cores* - do you know how many cores there are on any modern PC CPU (which is a SoC)? Can go up to **dozens** of different *architecture* cores for starters, and some of these are multicore by themselves. These FPGAs are designed for some range of uses, and if yours is outside of this range, then you should consider a different product.

Comment: I bet the marketing material will say what the expected uses are, but in general the A series is probably to run some kind of embedded OS while the R series is some realtime data management or processing task.

Comment: There are thousands of cores in GPUs and many many cores inside my laptop i9 processor. The question in my mind was, what is use of so many cores inside an FPGA. :) I guess I am not one of the people that need all that "heterogeneous processing", whatever that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple CPUs on an SoC FPGA have several typical applications, some examples being:

- Each CPU targeted to a specific task and I/O, either with private buses and/or memory and/or IO or shared with other CPUs.
- Two sets of CPU/memory with shared I/O for dual redundancy.
- Three CPUs connected in lock-step for triple-mode redundancy.

This list of examples far from not exhaustive, though I'll refrain from keeping tweaking it.

Many of these functions are found on microcontrollers and SoCs but without the FPGA gates, which is why they're made.

One thing's for sure: they will all be in there because enough customers requested them for specific applications they have. They'll have stayed on their product line-up because customers kept buying them. They're not made to see if they might sell. With the very large devices, it's typically relatively few customers buying relatively few parts at relatively very high cost (some many £k/part). Like most manufacturers, FPGA manufacturers are very market driven for their higher-end products.

Comment: +1 for last paragraph especially.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of both A53 and R5 cores is aimed at applications where both a significant amount of processing is required together with high safety requirements. This is especially a requirement for automotive applications.

The processing tasks are going to be divided into those that can be performed effectively by the FPGA fabric, such as spectral analysis (FFT) and beam forming, those that require more complex but less structured processing such as object detection, classification and tracking (A53 cores) and those requiring very high reliability such as safety monitoring (R5F cores).

For example:

[4D Imaging Radar for Autonomous Driving](https://www.xilinx.com/news/press/2020/xilinx-and-continental-collaborate-to-create-auto-industry-s-first-production-ready-4d-imaging-radar-for-autonomous-driving.html)